# Why is my .putExtra not passing information?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-recyclerview, android-room

I am creating an app similar to a notes app. I have an activity that is called `AddEditUserActivity`, and, as its name implies, it adds OR edits a `user` (the object that I created). When I click on a `user` on the RecyclerView, I am supposed to go to the `AddEditUserActivity` and see the 5 fields full with the info of the selected `user` with the title of the activity as "Edit User". When I create a new user, I am supposed to go to the same activity, but with the fields empty, and "Add User" as the title. Creating a user works fine, but when I try to edit it, the activity appears with "Add User" as a title and all the fields empty.

The strange thing is that I implemented some Toast messages like "User updated" and "User Created", and they show when they are supposed to. I think that the problem is in the `MainActivity`. When I click on a user, I `putExtra` to an Intent and then call `startActivityForResult(EDIT_USER_REQUEST, intent)`. In the `AddEditUserActivity`, inside `onCreate`, I specified that if the intent has a specific extra (the id) then it means that I am updating the user. But it ignores that part. So I would really appreciate it if you could help me.

Here is my MainActivity:

```
package com.example.citadelentrance;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.ItemTouchHelper;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;

import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final int ADD_USER_REQUEST = 1;
    public static final int EDIT_USER_REQUEST = 2;

    private UserViewModel userViewModel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FloatingActionButton addUserButton = findViewById(R.id.button_add_user);
        addUserButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddEditUserActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, ADD_USER_REQUEST);
            }
        });

        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        final UserAdapter adapter = new UserAdapter();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        userViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(UserViewModel.class);
        userViewModel.getAllUsers().observe(this, new Observer<List<User>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable List<User> users) {
                adapter.submitList(users);
            }
        });

        new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {
            @Override
            public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
                userViewModel.delete(adapter.getUserAt(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()));
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "User deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }).attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);

        adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new UserAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(User user) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddEditUserActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(AddEditUserActivity.EXTRA_ID, user.getId());
                intent.putExtra(AddEditUserActivity.EXTRA_NAME, user.getName());
                intent.putExtra(AddEditUserActivity.EXTRA_FAMILY, user.getFamily());
                intent.putExtra(AddEditUserActivity.EXTRA_LICENSE_PLATE, user.getLicensePlate());
                intent.putExtra(AddEditUserActivity.EXTRA_DOCUMENT, user.getDocument());
                intent.putExtra(AddEditUserActivity.EXTRA_ADDRESS, user.getAddress());
                intent.putExtra(AddEditUserActivity.EXTRA_TIME, user.getTime());
                startActivityForResult(intent, EDIT_USER_REQUEST);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == ADD_USER_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            assert data != null;
            String name = data.getStringExtra(AddEditUserActivity.EXTRA_NAME);
            String family = data.getStringExtra(AddEditUserActivity.EXTRA_FAMILY);
            String licensePlate = data.getStringExtra(AddEditUserActivity.EXTRA_LICENSE_PLATE);
            String document = data.getStringExtra(AddEditUserActivity.EXTRA_DOCUMENT);
            String address = data.getStringExtra(AddEditUserActivity.EXTRA_ADDRESS);
            String time = data.getStringExtra(AddEditUserActivity.EXTRA_TIME);

            User user = new User(
                    name,
                    family,
                    licensePlate,
                    document,
                    address,
                    time
            );
            userViewModel.insert(user);

            Toast.makeText(this, "User saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (requestCode == EDIT_USER_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            assert data != null;
            int id = data.getIntExtra(AddEditUserActivity.EXTRA_ID, -1);
            
            if (id == -1) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "User couldn't be updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            String name = data.getStringExtra(AddEditUserActivity.EXTRA_NAME);
            String family = data.getStringExtra(AddEditUserActivity.EXTRA_FAMILY);
            String licensePlate = data.getStringExtra(AddEditUserActivity.EXTRA_LICENSE_PLATE);
            String document = data.getStringExtra(AddEditUserActivity.EXTRA_DOCUMENT);
            String address = data.getStringExtra(AddEditUserActivity.EXTRA_ADDRESS);
            String time = data.getStringExtra(AddEditUserActivity.EXTRA_TIME);

            User user = new User(
                    name,
                    family,
                    licensePlate,
                    document,
                    address,
                    time
            );
            user.setId(id);
            userViewModel.update(user);

            Toast.makeText(this, "User updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "User not saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

And here the AddEditUserActivity:

```
package com.example.citadelentrance;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Objects;

public class AddEditUserActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String EXTRA_ID = "com.example.citadelentrance.EXTRA_ID";
    public static final String EXTRA_NAME = "com.example.citadelentrance.EXTRA_NAME";
    public static final String EXTRA_FAMILY = "com.example.citadelentrance.EXTRA_FAMILY";
    public static final String EXTRA_LICENSE_PLATE = "com.example.citadelentrance.EXTRA_LICENSE_PLATE";
    public static final String EXTRA_DOCUMENT = "com.example.citadelentrance.EXTRA_DOCUMENT";
    public static final String EXTRA_ADDRESS = "com.example.citadelentrance.EXTRA_ADDRESS";
    public static final String EXTRA_TIME = "com.example.citadelentrance.EXTRA_TIME";

    private EditText editTextName, editTextFamily,
            editTextLicensePlate, editTextDocument, editTextAddress;
    private TextView textViewTime;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_user);

        editTextName = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_name);
        editTextFamily = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_family);
        editTextLicensePlate = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_license_plate);
        editTextDocument = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_document);
        editTextAddress = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_address);
        textViewTime = findViewById(R.id.text_view_time);

        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_close);

        Intent intent = new Intent();

        if (intent.hasExtra(EXTRA_ID)) {
            setTitle("Edit User");
            editTextName.setText(intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_NAME));
            editTextFamily.setText(intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_FAMILY));
            editTextLicensePlate.setText(intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_LICENSE_PLATE));
            editTextDocument.setText(intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_DOCUMENT));
            editTextAddress.setText(intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_ADDRESS));
            textViewTime.setText(intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_TIME));
        } else {
            setTitle("Add User");
            textViewTime.setText(LocalDateTimeConverter.toDateString(LocalDateTime.now()));
            Log.println(Log.ASSERT, "CS50x", "Add user activity");
        }
    }

    private void saveUser() {
        String name = getTextFromEdit(editTextName);
        String family = getTextFromEdit(editTextFamily);
        String licensePlate = getTextFromEdit(editTextLicensePlate);
        String document = getTextFromEdit(editTextDocument);
        String address = getTextFromEdit(editTextAddress);
        String time = textViewTime.toString();

        if (name.isEmpty() || family.isEmpty() || licensePlate.isEmpty() ||
                document.isEmpty() || address.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please don't leave empty fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        Intent data = new Intent();
        data.putExtra(EXTRA_NAME, name);
        data.putExtra(EXTRA_FAMILY, family);
        data.putExtra(EXTRA_LICENSE_PLATE, licensePlate);
        data.putExtra(EXTRA_DOCUMENT, document);
        data.putExtra(EXTRA_ADDRESS, address);
        data.putExtra(EXTRA_TIME, time);

        int id = getIntent().getIntExtra(EXTRA_ID, -1);
        if (id != -1) {
            data.putExtra(EXTRA_ID, id);
            Log.println(Log.ASSERT, "CS50x", "id != -1");
        }

        setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_save_user, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.save_user) {
            saveUser();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private String getTextFromEdit(EditText editText) {
        return editText.getText().toString().trim();
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you need obtain the current Intent (which came from MainActivity) by calling getIntent() in AddEditUserActivity.onCreate(), just as you are properly doing so inside AddEditUserActivity.saveUser(). The newly created instance of Intent would never have relevant extra data (EXTRA_ID).

Comment: Indeed, it was that. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@arget's comment is correct - you need to change this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
```

to this

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
```

or use it directly instead.

Another thing, why don't you make the user class implement Parcelable, and pass the user around instead of all its properties? It would make the code a cleaner.

Comment: `why don't you make the user class extend Parcelable` you may want to correct your answer. Parcelable cannot be extended. It's an interface so it can only be implemented.